# Apollo client fetchMore does not update variables

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo-client

I have used a query in this manner:

```
const { data, refetch, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery<{ personComments: PersonCommentConnection }>(
    PERSON_GET_COMMENT,
    {
      fetchPolicy,
      variables,
      skip: !isBrowser,
      onCompleted: () => setInitializedQuery(true),
    }
  )
```

and a fetch more function

```
const fetchMorePersonComments = async () => {
    setFetchingMore(true)

    await fetchMore({
      variables: {
        after: data?.personComments.pageInfo.endCursor,
      },
      updateQuery: (
        previousEntries,
        { fetchMoreResult, variables }
      ): { personComments: PersonCommentConnection } => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult) {
          return previousEntries
        }

        if (fetchMoreResult) {
          fetchMoreResult.personComments.edges = [
            ...previousEntries.personComments.edges,
            ...fetchMoreResult.personComments.edges,
          ]
        }

        return fetchMoreResult
      },
    })

    setFetchingMore(false)
  }
```

I used infinite scrolling to call fetchmore comments but when it's been called It only refetches the first query instead of adding the after query.

**Note I've successfully created queries similar to this one but only fails for this**

Do you have any ideas why during in the fetchmore query it does not update the query variables.

Comment: may be the updated data not getting add up in previousEntries. If you remove the updateQuery, Does fetchMore give new data ?

Comment: else can try - 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/#merging-paginated-results